# Sidepanel with Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, dockpanel

I'd like to implement a sidepanel in my Qt window. I search something like the one that is used in the Visual Studio (see below).

[image]

Important notes:

- The widgets don't have to be moveable
- resizing should be possible
- each widget should be clearly separated from the other layout

Does anyone have an idea how I could build such a sidepanel? (Maybe there even exists a library)
Or does anyone know a project which uses Qt and some kind of sidepanel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use [`QDockWidgets`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdockwidget.html). That's the type of thing they are intended for inside a `QMainWindow`.

You can put toolbars, QTreeViews and QTableViews (or related) widgets inside your dock widget to simulate the screenshot you posted.

For an example usage: [Dock Widgets Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html).